# Pencil Coil Operation

Tags: engine-theory, ignition

Pencil coils are very small. Do they operate on the CDI Principle? I thought that CDI was not good on lean mixtures which are good for fuel economy? Do they operate on the accepted Inductive Discharge Principle? I thought that inductive discharge benefited from a big coil to store lots of energy for a big spark? Do they operate like a T Coil? Do they use some Resonant Scheme?